# How to force GC on Android system process?

Tags: android, garbage-collection

In an old [Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/ZhaECpJJo5Q), Romain Guy says,

> When you do this kind of test, you should force GCs on the system
>   process with DDMS, then force GCs in your process and then check how
>   many activities you have running.

How does one force GC on the system process?

Comment: I think you might need a rooted device to see this. In DDMS I can see the `system_process` along with the `Cause GC` button

Comment: Good catch @daentech!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Device Monitor select the `system_process` and click the `Cause GC` trash can icon.

[image: Cause GC]

**Edit:** daentech appears to be correct regarding root access. The screenshot I included is from a rooted test device. When I connect my daily use, non-rooted, device I do not see any processes except the ones I am debugging.

Comment: Bummer about requiring root.  That explains why I couldn't find it.